PHPUnit tests throws Call to undefined method for assertions while testing APIs
I have developed a set of API's using the API Platform 3.4 for Symfony 6.4. I have written test cases using PHPUnit, However running the tests throws the following error
Error: Call to undefined method ApiPlatform\Symfony\Bundle\Test\Response::assertResponseIsSuccessful()

My test script is :
namespace App\Tests\Api;

use \Datetime;
use ApiPlatform\Symfony\Bundle\Test\ApiTestCase;
//use ApiPlatform\Symfony\Bundle\Test\Client;
use App\Entity\Carrier;

class CarrierTest extends ApiTestCase
{
    public function testCreateCarrier(): void
    {
        $response = static::createClient()->request('POST', '/api/carriers`',
          ['json' => [
                     'CarrierName' => 'Name of the Carrier',
                     'CarrierCode' => 'CARR1',
                     'CarrierDoorOrPOBoxNumber' => '56A',
                     'CarrierBuildingName' => '',
                     'CarrierStreetName' => 'First Street',
                     'CarrierLocality' => 'Locality',
                     'CarrierStateOrCounty' => 'TN',
                     'CarrierCountry' => 'India',
                     'CarrierPostalCode' => '563115',
                     'AccountManager' => 'Account Manager 1',
                     'AccountNumber' => 'TBC',
                     'CarrierPhoneNumber' => '',
                     'CarrierEmail' => 'am1@c1.com',
                     'CarrierLogo' => '',
        ]]);
        $response->assertResponseIsSuccessful();
        $response->assertResponseStatusCodeSame(201);
    }
}

Inspite of digging deep in the API Platform documentation I am unable to come across anything concrete to resolve this. I have had no problems with PHP Unit tests in Symfony 5.x. Any sugesstion what I could be missing.
